Can my boss say/do this
I have a question but in order to ask I need to explain quickly.
On a Friday I had heard a staff member of discriminating against another staff member I directly told her that what she said sounds like dis and we could all get into trouble if the other staff member heard her it ended up with me asking her to leave me alone to finish my lunch break and when she did she went directly to speak ill of me to my teammate. Because of this outrageous behaviour I had to speak with the supervisor and explain what happened.
The following week the same staff member ignored me up till Wednesday when I was sent to speak with our manager who asked about the "drama" that happened on Friday in my eyes nothing resulted in a big drama I explained what happened and she told me that it was everyone (obviously including me) who had discrimination against the other staff member by "laughing behind her back" I was shocked by this accusation and tried to clear my name but she just resisted the accusation leaving me very uncomfortable she then told me that I had to "make up" with the colleague who I had said was discriminating otherwise my manager will "bring us both into the office and treat us like kids".
After this I felt forced and worried for my job the following day I was told that the staff member won't speak with me because she was told that I had gone to our supervisor on the same day (Friday) and complained about her. In my eyes that was breaking confidentiality agreement because that should of stayed private now I feel uncomfortable telling my management any information or speaking up against wrong doings in the future. Should I leave it or speak with HR??
Can someone help?

I'm confused by your description - who is who and what role do they have? So exactly are the "supervisor", "manager" and "boss" you speak of - are they one and the same, are they different persons? Who did you explain to what happened (second paragraph) - your manager or the staff member you have a conflict with? Does the staff member you are in conflict with have any leverage on your position, or are you at equal levels? Did you actually go to your "supervisor on the same day (Friday) and complained about her" or is that a story someone made up?

I have no doubt that if I heard you explain it, I'd be able to follow your meaning — but I'm afraid your writing (and especially lack of punctuation and sentence breaks) makes it pretty hard to decipher.

People at work don't play fair
When you had words with your co-worker you put them on defense, so they took the offense to you by reporting to your boss.  So your boss doesn't know what happened.  HR doesn't know what happened.  What your boss gets is drama from two employees.  Next time either report what a person says or let it be.  You the co-worker aren't going to change someone, but you can put fear in them and scared people can lash out and hit you.
Do not go to HR about your boss unless it's worth losing your job over.  The first person HR will talk to is your boss.  Is that what you want, to battle your boss?  HR works for management, not the workers.

Without knowing what was said, it is hard to advise.
As a general rule though:

Remarks made against protected characteristics (Race, Gender, Sexual orientation etc.) should always be reported.
Remarks that are serious abuse should always be reported.
Sustained and demonstrable abuse (not necessarily serious) should always be reported.

So, for example - say you are working with someone and you hear them use racial slurs - absolutely report.
If you heard someone swearing at someone, report that.
If you heard someone continuously say things like 'You are useless here, why don't you quit' and 'Just go home, we work better without you' - whilst not as vulgar or illegal as the above, if it is repeated - report it.
Below that, it depends whether or not you have people or evidence that can confirm your side of the story. He-said/She-said situations are difficult to prove and absent a 3rd party or evidence, it may or may not be advisable to report it - insofar that it would be better to wait until you had better information to go to Management/HR so that you are believed.
